# Vue.js 3 Composition API ссылки из svg в router-link

Tags: vue.js, svg, vue-router

У меня есть svg файл (карта оборудования), в котором есть ссылки на 3-д модели. Я хочу при клике по ссылке из svg файла открывать новый маршрут и подгружать свою 3-д модель, это работает с одним но - страница полностью перезагружается и дублируются все компоненты - то есть появляется 2 меню, 2 футера.
Я считаю, что необходимо каким-то образом перехватить HTML ссылки из svg и переделать их в router-link. Единственное решение, которое смог найти https://dennisreimann.de/articles/delegating-html-links-to-vue-router.html , но у меня не получается его адаптировать и заставить работать.

В шаблоне подключаю svg через тег object

```
 <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-12 flex justify-content-center align-items-center princip-plan" @click="clickSVG">
        <object  type="image/svg+xml" :data="getModelBN800.link"> </object>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

export default {
    

    setup() {
        onMounted(() => {
        })

        const modelStore = useModelStore()
        const { getModelBN800 } = storeToRefs(modelStore)

        const clickSVG = (event) => {
            console.log(event)      
            let  target  = event
            while (target && target.tagName !== 'A') target = target.parentNode
            if (target && target.matches(".dynamic-content a:not([href*='://'])") && target.href) {
             if (button !== undefined && button !== 0) return
             if (target && target.getAttribute) {
                    const linkTarget = target.getAttribute('target')
                     if (/\b_blank\b/i.test(linkTarget)) return
                 }
                 const url = new URL(target.href)
                 const to = url.pathname
                 if (window.location.pathname !== to && event.preventDefault) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                     this.$router.push(to)
                 }
             }
        }

        return { getModelBN800, clickSVG }

    }
}
</script>
```

Сейчас функция clickSVG  ни как не реагирует. Если я добавлю стиль `pointer-events:none;` к object тогда клик срабатывает, но target.tagName не находит ссылок, а только div на котором повешен клик. Если повесить клик на object, ни каких действий не происходит. Какие есть варианты решения моей задачи?

На основе решения Александра Сычева (ниже в комментариях). Я попытался адаптировать решение для себя и получаю ошибку `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentDocument')` .
Я создал функцию clickSVG2 и добавил ее в onMounted:

```
 onMounted(() => {
              
                clickSVG2()
            })   
const clickSVG2 = () => {
                window.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    // const a = ref(null)
                    // console.log(a.value)
                    const a = document.getElementById("Plan").contentDocument
                    const b = a.getElementById("svg4504")
                    const c = b.querySelectorAll("a")
                    c.forEach(i => {
                        i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                            e.preventDefault()
                            console.log(i)
                        })
                    })
                });
            }
```

Я добавил  id="Plan" в object, а внутри моего svg  файла id svg4504. Также я пытался повесить ссылку ref на object, но также безрезультатно.
Также я должен сообщить, что не могу разместить svg inline, ибо файл является сложным и в нем 40К строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то главная проблема, получить `url` ссылки из `svg`  --- написал на `js`, под `vue` адаптируете сами --- ( как вариант на `mounted()` установить )

**Пример svg:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:7;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
    <a id="ancor0" href="/ancor0">
        <rect height="17.3" width="7" x="100.7" y="116.5"/>
    </a>
    <a id="ancor1" href="/ancor1">
        <rect height="17.3" width="7" x="117.7" y="116.5"/>
    </a>
    <a id="ancor2" href="/ancor2">
        <rect height="17.3" width="7" x="133.7" y="116.5"/>
    </a>
    <a id="ancor3" href="/ancor3">
        <rect height="17.3" fill="red" width="7" x="148.7" y="116.5"/>
    </a>
</svg>
```

**Поиск на js:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const a = document.getElementById("svgObject").contentDocument
  const b = a.getElementById("Layer_1")
  const c = b.querySelectorAll("a")
  c.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(i)
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<div>
  <object id="svgObject" data="1489437033-house10_81899.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%">
Your browser doesn't support SVG
</object>
</div>
```

обязательно нужно дождаться загрузки всех файлов
`window.addEventListener("load", () => {...`

Comment: Да, похоже это то что нужно. Но я получаю ошибку, добавил код и описание в основной вопрос

Comment: есть локальный сервер? попробуйте на нем на js, с моей свг для простоты - мне отпишите

Comment: Да. я работаю на локальном сервере. Я сохранил вашу svg и попробовал с ней, результат тот же ```Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentDocument')``` Не получается получить доступ к contentDocument. Я также пробовал метод getSVGDocument и с ним поведение аналогичное

Comment: закинул на хостирг показать вам - http://calc.helpsycheva.ru/234.html. Всё тоже самое, что в ответе написал

Comment: В общем svg не успевал загрузиться, установит таймаут и contentDocument теперь отрабатывает без ошибки. Пытаюсь далее решить свою задачу. Благодарю вас

Comment: Я победил) Спасибо вам огромное за помощь. Выше прикрепил решение

Comment: пожалуйста, рад был помочь =)

Answer (score 1):

Так как svg не успевал загрузиться, то сделал через SetTimeout и все прекрасно работает. Нахожу все ссылки в svg, из них достаю id (заранее известно, что id будет в конце ссылки) и вешаю клик обработчик, который отменяет действие по умолчанию и пушит на нужный маршрут. Функцию ниже надо вешать в блок setup - onMounted. Благодарю  Александра Сычева за помощь в решении.

```
const linksReplacement = () => {
            setTimeout(function(){
                 const object = document.getElementById("Plan").contentDocument
                 const svg = object.getElementById("svg4504")
                 const links = svg.querySelectorAll("a")
                 console.log(links);
                links.forEach(link => {
                    link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                         e.preventDefault()
                         let url = link.href.baseVal
                         //let id = url.split('/').splice(-1, 1)
                         let id = url.split('/').pop()
                         console.log(id)
                         router.push({
                             name: 'info.models.show',
                             params: {
                                 id: id,
                             },
                         })
                     })
                 })
            }, 1000)
        }
```